# Apache Derby EmbeddedDataSource no longer available

Tags: java, derby

I was using a 10.8.x.x version of Apache Derby and utilizing the EmbeddedDataSource class. I can't seem to find a non interface replacement. I was able to find the classes located in org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc. which contains an EmbeddeDataSource interface, but no actual implementation of the class. Was this moved somewhere or is there an alternative class I can use? I haven't been able to find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to upgrade Derby from 10.8.x.x to 10.15.x.x or higher?

In that case you need to additionally add the artifact `derbytools` to the artifacts `derby` and `derbyshared` that you probably already have on the classpath.

With release 10.15.1.3, Derby has been modularized and the classes have been rearranged a bit. `EmbeddedDataSource` is now in `derbytools.jar`: https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.15.1.3.html

Answer (score 0):

EmbeddedDataSource is not supported with 10.15.x version. One might be using Derby version 10.14.x. If someone is working with Derby version 10.15.x or 10.16.x, they will no longer be able to use EmbeddedDataSource until and unless they do not add derbytools.jar in their POM file.

With the new Derby version upgrade (10.15.x and 10.16.x), a new jar file (derbyshared.jar) has been added. All Derby configurations require it. In addition, the derbytools.jar library is now required when running the network server, when using Derby DataSources, and when directly referencing the JDBC drivers. Below dependency is to be added additionally in POM-

groupId: org.apache.derby
artifactId: derbytools

Reference: https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.15.1.3.html